# drush open_basedir restriction in effect on media temple

Tags: drush

I'm using drush on mediatemple grid service. I think i've got setup drush correctly. At least to my knowledge. I've been able to use it; but with nagging errors/warnings each time.

And whenever i invoke drush i get these errors:

`The following restricted PHP modes have non-empty values: check your configuration settings in /usr/local/php-5.2.14/etc/php.ini or in your drush.ini file`

Anyone have any clues how to rectify this?

Comment: Answer is actually found here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10372/drush-open-basedir-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting an alias for drush allowed me to fix this issue:

> alias drush='/usr/bin/php5 -c /home/000000/etc/drush.ini
>   ~/bin/drush/drush.php'

Answer (score 1):

```
drush topic docs-ini-files
```

That command tells more about creating a drush.ini file. In it, you want to remove the listed restrictions (you didn't provide them).

Answer (score 0):

Because making an alias for `drush.php` is not covered in `drush-5.x` Readme file. A better solution is to copy the server's default configuration `php.ini` file to `$HOME/.drush` or to `/etc/drush`.

Then, edit it to set `open_basedir` to no value and add any other custom configuration for crush.

Sample of drush specific `php.ini` file:

```
# Drush configuration
open_basedir=
safe_mode=
disable_functions=
disable_classes=
magic_quotes_gpc=
```

Hope this helps.