# Setting up drush ini path in my site alias

Tags: drush

Unfortunately, i use shared hosting for my dev site to show to clients.

I'd like to specify an ini path in my `example.aliases.drush.php` file.

I couldn't find that particular custom variable in the example file.

Is it possible to set the drush.ini path so i don't get these nagging [open basedir](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10372/drush-open-basedir-error) errors?

```
<?php
        $aliases['dev'] = array(
        'remote-host' => 'foohost',
        'root' => '/home/xxxxxx/users/.home/domains/xxxxxx/html',
        'php' => '/usr/bin/php',
        'path-aliases' => array(
         '%drush' => '$HOME/bin/drush/',
         '%drush-ini'=>'/home/xxxxxx/etc/drush.ini',
         '%drush-script' => '$HOME/bin/drush/drush/drush.php',
         '%dump' => ' ../db/dev.xxx.sql',
        '%files' => 'sites/all/files',
        ),
    );
```

Comment: buddy you raised a good question - you deserve a monster congrats - sure thing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drush processes drush.ini in the drush bash script prior to calling drush.php.  Here is the relevant code it uses:

```
for conf_dir in $(dirname "$SELF_PATH") /etc/drush $HOME/.drush ; do
  if [ -f $conf_dir/php.ini ] ; then
    drush_php_ini=$conf_dir/php.ini
  fi
  if [ -f $conf_dir/drush.ini ] ; then
    drush_php_override=$conf_dir/drush.ini
  fi
done
```

You will need to make sure that your drush.ini file is in one of those location in order for it to be found and processed.  Note that the drush bash script never acts on command line parameters; those are parsed in php.  There are some environment variables that affect the drush bash script, but there are no environment variables that affect the selection of drush.ini, and there is no facility in site aliases to pass environment variable values to drush on the remote machine.

Sorry.

**Edit:** You could try setting %drush-script in your alias file to point to a script on the remote machine that called `php /path/to/drush/drush.php`.  Read the advice in the README.txt for Drush-4 on how to make an alias to drush.php if you do this; you will want to make sure that --php is passed to Drush correctly, etc.